# Python guessing game keeps return same output

Tags: python, random

I am trying to create a python function that makes you guess a number 0 - 100. 
 Every time I run the code, it always prints lower, even when I put the lowest number possible(0). How can I prevent this and have my code run correctly.

Here is my code:

```
from random import *
z = False

def whle(i):
    x = raw_input("Guess My Number 1 - 100")
    if x < i:
        print "Higher"
        q = False
        z = True
    elif x > i:
        print "Lower"
        q = False
        z = True
    elif x == i:
        print "Correct!"
        q = True
        z = False
    else:
        print "Guess My Number You Goofy Goose!"
        q = False
        z = True
def number():
    y = randrange(0,101)
    q = False
    while q == False:
       whle(y)
while z == False:
    number()
```

Comment: `x` can be bigger then `i`, lower then `i` or equal `i` - so `else` never happen. You never see "Guess My Number You Goofy Goose!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string, so you need to wrap it with a call to `int()`. Like this:

```
    x = int(raw_input("Guess My Number 1 - 100"))
```

You shouldn't be able to compare those types, and `'1' > 1` returning `True` is a bug in Python 2. Python 3 deals with it correctly:

```
Python 3.4.3+ (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:03:50) 
>>> '1' > 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

Comment: I don't get your point about `ord`. I entered `"1" > 5000` into my python2 interpreter and it said `True`.

Comment: @Score_Under you're completely right. I removed that and added the correct information.

Answer (score 1):

Your `raw_input` is giving you a string. You should coerce it to an `int`:

```
    x = raw_input("Guess My Number 1 - 100")
    x = int(x)
```

That will fix your code.

You would not have come across this issue if you started using Python 3, because it would give you an error instead of allowing you to make comparisons between `str` and `int` types (which give nonsense results in Python 2).

You will also need to add `global` declarations to your code for the `q` and `z` variables:

```
def whle(i):
    global q
    global z
    # ...

def number():
    global q
```

This will allow you to overwrite them in the global namespace. Normally you would just be creating an identically named local variable which shadows the global, and that means your changes won't be visible to the rest of the program (because they're not changes).

However I think the logic for `q` and `z` do need rethinking a little: in the original script, only one is ever set to `True` at a time, but `q` has to be `True` in order for your program to check `z`'s value. Together, that means that whenever your program checks `z` it will be `False`. This will need re-thinking; do you want to remove the variable entirely, or change how `q` and `z` are set?

---

Below this line are things which are not as necessary, but which I'd still recommend.

---

You might also want to check for invalid input, by catching a resulting `ValueError`:

```
    x = raw_input("Guess My Number 1 - 100")
    try:
        x = int(x)
    except ValueError:
        print "That's not a number"
        return
```

I would very much recommend renaming *all* of your functions and variables. `q` → `guessed_correctly`, `z` → `user_quit`, `x` → `guess`, `i` → `target`, `whle` → `take_guess`, `number` → `new_game`. (Or something to that effect)

If you put a newline (`\n`) at the end of your prompt for `raw_input`, it will be a lot less confusing to the user.

There is more in this code that could do with some tweaking but I think I'll leave you there.

Answer (score 0):

You need get int() from raw and check with try if you get string.

```
from random import randrange

start_againg = True
max_number = 100
count_possible = 5

while start_againg is True:
    count_possible -= 1
    random_number = randrange(0, max_number + 1)

    try:
        number = int(raw_input("Guess My Number 1 - {0}\n".format(max_number)))

        if number < random_number:
            print "Higher"
        elif number > random_number:
            print "lower"
        elif number == random_number:
            print "correct"
            start_againg = False

        if count_possible == 0:
            print "attempts ended"
            start_againg = False

    except Exception, e:
        print "Guess my NUMBER, not string!"
```

Comment: I'll give the same comment here as to Kos: I don't think a rewrite will help the OP figure out what is wrong with their code. Since it looks like a question an early Python learner might ask, I think you should try to make your response as educational as possible.

Answer (score 0):

There's a much shorter way to do this.

```
from random import randint

while True:
    n = randint(0,100)
    while True:
        guess = int(input('> '))
        if guess>n:
            print('Higher')
        elif guess<n:
            print('Lower')
        elif guess==n:
            print('Correct!')
            break
        else:
            print('Guess My Number You Goofy Goose!')
```

Comment: Going to say the same thing as to Kos and JRazor: You shouldn't just write a code answer. The OP has asked a question which sounds like one a Python learner would ask, so it would be more helpful to help the asker figure out the problem and educate them as to how to avoid it, than to show what the problem looks like when solved.

Comment: If you'd like a silly analogy, posting a working solution in a question like this is like giving a solved rubik's cube to someone struggling to figure one out. Yes, it's the solution to the problem, but it's not what they're after.